# how do i connect surface mount dot to a track in altium designer?

Tags: altium

I am new to altium pcb designer and i am working on led panel project ,
I am making pcb for this led panel board ,
I am using single sided pcb .
all series and parallel combination of surface mount led is on top layer of the pcb ,
i am just simply wants to give supply to the led panel via led panel driver
 using wires to led panel.
for that I am plotting two surface mount pad of diameter 5 mm on top layer off the pcb ,
as I am using single sided pcb I can not use two pin header here 
only solution is surface mount pad . 
out of this two pad one pad is positive and one pad is negative 
I want to connect this positive pad to anode of led and negative pad to cathode of led but interactive routing does not allow me to do this.
So I want to do this forcefully can anybody give me suggestion 
what can I do for solving this problem ?
Please forgive me for my poor english please refer below image to understand it fully 
thank you !!!!
[image]

Comment: Have you got a component in your schematic for the pads you want connected to the appropriate nets?

Comment: no which component should i use in schematic ?

Comment: Did you draw s schematic in Altium? Only if the pads are set to the same "NETname" you are allowed to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a component in Altium with the pad as a footprint and connect it to the correct nets in the schematic, or you can simply place a pad in the PCB and manually change the "Net" dropdown to the same net name as the track. This will tell the PCB editor that the track is supposed to connect to that net.

Comment: Woops, looks like you may have already figured this out. Didn't read the comments of the original post.